# S3: No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, cors

I've got a S3 bucket in the `eu-west-1` region, let's call it `my-bucket`.

In that bucket there's a picture, let's call it `some-file.jpg`.

If I access both these urls through the browser, I can retrieve that picture (all objects in the bucket are public) (remember that these are examples, not real-life urls):

https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/some-file.jpg

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/some-file.jpg

However, I'm trying to get some info on that picture, and for that I'm using vibrant.js, which attempts to retrieve the file.

However, it fails when the url is: https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/some-file.jpg, with the following CORS error:

```
Access to Image at 'https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/some-file.jpg' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://example.com' is therefore not allowed access
```

I've made sure that the bucket's CORS policy accepts all origins:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

My guess is that https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/some-file.jpg sends the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and the other one doesn't. How can I solve this?

Comment: The problem probably isn't the URLs -- that is likely coincidental.  If you clear your browser's cache, you should find they both behave the same, and neither will work.  S3 has historically had an issue that surfaces when you request an object twice like this, once from HTML and once from JavaScript, described more fully at https://serverfault.com/a/856948/15316.  That question mentions CloudFront, but the issue occurs independent of whether or not you are using CloudFront.

Answer (score 14):

Did you clear your browser cache after updating the CORS headers

The problem I had was that **Chrome was caching the image with the headers (not containing the CORS data)**, so no matter what I tried to change in AWS, I would not see my CORS headers.

After **clearing Chrome cache and reloading the page**, the image had the expected CORS Headers

Comment: I had this problem and solved it by deleting all of the cached IndexedDB instances.  This approach was inspired by this answer.

Comment: It works for me. This is a hard to detect problem for me

Answer (score -4):

Try to run the image through CORS proxy.

```
fetch('https://cors.now.sh/https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/some-file.jpg')
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)
```

This looks like a hack but worked perfectly for me.