# Why am I having the "CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing" error when accessing an AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I am having a persistent issue with the "CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing" error when accessing medical images uploaded to an AWS S3 bucket from my Rails site (localhost:3000).

Here is my CORS configuration.

```
[
  {
    "AllowedHeaders": [],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
  }
]
```

Here is the issue I am having in Firefox (Just for your information, there are 16 images that need to load up).

[image: CORS error]

I am not an expert in AWS or CORS configurations, but I don't know where to begin. My understanding is that I am allowing requests from ALL origins, so I wonder why this error is occurring.

The error tells me that the ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is missing. But where is this specified in the CORS file? Many similar questions are on SO, but they are pre-JSON CORS files for AWS.

Am I correct in my understanding that this CORS configuration should, in principle allow requests for ALL referrers (sites)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following for the CORS configuration on the AWS Console side:

```
[
  {
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ]
  }
]
```

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ManageCorsUsing.html for more info on AWS S3 CORS configurations.

Comment: Thanks for this; unfortunately, this makes no difference which makes no sense to me at all. Using the header wildcard should make all headers permissible?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache or using an Incognito window to clear the cached headers? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54592150/13690747